# Running multiple test in selenium in single session

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I would like to run multiple tests after sign in to my test site. But the chrome browser is closing after the execution of each test. I would highly appreciate anyone can help.

**main.py**

```
    class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):
    """A sample test class to show how page object works"""

    
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.driver.get("===========")
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    def test_SignIn(self):
        driver = self.driver
        Login = LoginPage(driver)
        Login.enterEmail('any@gmail.com')
        Login.enterPassword('abc123')
        Login.clickSignIn()
        time.sleep(10)

    def test_ValueCalculator(self):
        driver = self.driver
        calculateValue = ValueCalculator(driver)
        calculateValue.enterSalary('kkk')
        calculateValue.enterSalarydifference('kkk')
        calculateValue.clickSubmit()
        time.sleep(10)

    
    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
   if __name__ == "__main__":
       unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use threads.

```py
from threading import Thread

t1 = Thread(target = your_method1)
t2 = Thread(target = your_method2)

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
```